# Google Analytics stopped gathering data when migrated to gtag.js

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

I have an angular.js webapp and I´m using Google Analytics. On 16/11 I migrated my angular webapp from the old universal google-analytics.js script to the new gtag.js. Next day, I stopped to getting analytics information. See the screenshot.
[image]

Some considerations:

1. I just migrated the js in the webapp.
2. I didn´t change any configuration in Google Analytics.
3. With the purpose to filter spam or ghost visits in GA, since a long time ago I had a filter that I "expected" to allow analytics only from my site, like:
   [image]
4. I have another view without any filter that I have noticed that seems to work. So for some reason the root cause could be the filter.
5. Also, I have noticed the real-time reports are not working in the filtered view, however, they are working in the not filtered view.
6. For testing purposes, I have just deleted the filter and the real-time reports are working.

As before the migration, I was gathering analytics, I think there are maybe different problems:
- It looks like the filter is (and was before the migration) preventing the real-time reports to work.
- Apart from the real-time reports, the analytics were working before the migration with the filter, so is there anything that needs to be changed, updated in analytics in order the gtag.js works. Or maybe gtag.js is working in a different way that makes analytics not work with that filter? 
- Should I delete the filter in any case? At the moment, I have deleted it and I will observe what happens with the analytics next days. However, if I delete the filter the spam analytics will come back. Maybe there is another filter that has to be applied.

UPDATE:
I attach the Gtag.js script in the website:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-property-1"></script>
    <script>
      var gaEnv;
      switch (window.location.hostname) {
        case 'www.domain.com':
            gaEnv = 'UA-property-1'; // production
            break;
        case 'www.test.domain.com':
            gaEnv = 'UA-property-3'; // test
            break;
        default:
            gaEnv = 'UA-property-2'; // development
      }
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      // Config for analytics
      gtag('config', gaEnv, { 'send_page_view': false });
      // Config for Adwords   
      gtag('config', 'AW-property');
    </script>
```

As I use Angularjs I hace developed a service to track page views, like:

```
service.trackPageView = function (url) {      
      gtag('config', trackingId, {'page_location': url});      
      /* Old code for google-analytics.js. deprecated with gtag.js
       * ga('set', 'page', url);
       * ga('send', 'pageview', url); */       
    };
```

UPDATE 2: I have installed Google Tag Assistant. It looks like it´s gathering the data and tracking the pageviews. The only strange thing that I see is the alert: This hit is missing the hostname in the URI.

UPDATE 3: As I suspected, when I delete the "include only" my hostname filter in the analytics view, the data is gathered again as you can see in the pic.

[image]

So, it´s pretty clear that gtag.js is sendind data from the app to Analytics to the right property.

Now, the only point is that I had that filter that I have deleted to filter the ghost analytics spam. So, I assume it will be back soon. Again to the starting point. 
My concern is if it´s maybe related to the info that I send to analytics or maybe the filter was wrong. So, I think I will need help to setup the filter working properly with this gtag.js library.

Comment: Can you provide some details on the changes you've made to your app? Provide some examples of where you've implemented the gtag.js code on page and examples of where you're sending data to GA via the gtag.js functions.

Comment: Please, see my updates.

Comment: For your error, can you provide an example of what “url” looks like when you pass it into function? I suspect that might be the issue.

Comment: Please, see my new UPDATE3. Maybe you get new conclusions.